# Convert existing app into a shortcut to a responsive site through an update

Tags: android, ios, google-play, app-store

I have an app currently in the app store that is using an outdated API (non-functioning) and would take a long time to convert it to using the new API. I have a responsive site that uses the new API and is perfectly capable of replacing this old app. The problem is our users already have this old app downloaded and use it. Is there a way to update the existing app in both the Apple and Google Play stores to be a shortcut that opens a browser and points it to our responsive site?

I know people can manually place URL shortcuts on their homepages, but I want to convert the icon that would normally open our old app into a URL shortcut. Is that possible?

Comment: You can't do this on iOS.

Comment: What @Paulw11 means is that it goes against Apple's policy. They eon't approve an app that only opens a web view to a website

Comment: Also there is no way that an app can create a web shortcut the app itself would need to be the web wrapper and that isn't permitted as you say